# How to enumerate groups of partitions in my Postgres table with window functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning, window-functions

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id  | part  | value
----+-------+-------
 1  | 0     | 8
 2  | 0     | 3
 3  | 0     | 4
 4  | 1     | 6
 5  | 0     | 13
 6  | 0     | 4
 7  | 1     | 2
 8  | 0     | 11
 9  | 0     | 15
 10 | 0     | 3
 11 | 0     | 2
```

I would like to enumerate groups between rows that have part atribute 1.

So I would like to get this:

```
id  | part  | value | number
----+-------+-----------------
 1  | 0     | 8     |   1
 2  | 0     | 3     |   1
 3  | 0     | 4     |   1
 4  | 1     | 6     |   0
 5  | 0     | 13    |   2
 6  | 0     | 4     |   2
 7  | 1     | 2     |   0
 8  | 0     | 11    |   3
 9  | 0     | 15    |   3
 10 | 0     | 3     |   3
 11 | 0     | 2     |   3
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Postgres window functions or is there any other way?

Comment: i do not understand the numbering and "wierd" order within the expected results off the number column.. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is different because in previous question I asked for enumerating inside partitions and here I'm asking about enumerating from the outside.

Comment: We don't understand that "enumerating from the outside". You'll have to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Yes i see your other question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984611/enumerating-table-partitions-in-postgres-table ) which makes more sense.. Because the number column follows a very direct algorithm.. The number in this question does not seam to follows a very direct algorithm..

Comment: I just want to divide table in certain parts and these parts need to have some number that defines them and also separates them from other parts of the table. The part of the table starts when part column is 1 and where the zeros are this is the whole part which end with part column again being 1.

Comment: Besides `7  | 1     | 2     |   2`  is i believe wrong in the expected output. number column should be 0 because column part is 1  just like `4  | 1     | 6     |   0`... Then why is number 1 within this record `8  | 0     | 11    |   1`  it feels wierd between other records which contains 0 and 3 as number column

Comment: Aha yes I see. Now I edited that part where the mistakes were before.

Comment: "Yes I see. Now I edited that part" Right! Now your question makes sense and number column follows a direct algorithm

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I am sorry for the mistakes. Do you what kind of query would give an output like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want something like 1 more than the cumulative sum of the parts.  The simplest method is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when part = 1 then 0  -- the easy case
             else 1 + sum(part) over (order by id)
        end) as number
from t;
```

If `part` can take on values other than 0 and 1:

```
select t.*,
       (case when part = 1 then 0  -- the easy case
             else 1 + sum( (part = 1)::int ) over (order by id)
        end) as number
from t;
```

Comment: very nice                   solution

Answer (score 2):

If i correctly understand, you need something like:

```
with t(id  , part  , value) as(
values
(1  , 0     , 8),
(2  , 0     , 3),
(3  , 0     , 4),
(4  , 1     , 6),
(5  , 0     , 13),
(6  , 0     , 4),
(7  , 1     , 2),
(8  , 0     , 11),
(9  , 0     , 15),
(10 , 0     , 3),
(11 , 0     , 2)
)

select id, part, value, case when  part = 1 then 0 else dense_rank() over(order by grp) end as result
from (
    select *,
    row_number() over(order  by id)   -
    row_number() over(partition by part order  by id) as grp
    from t
    order by id
) tt
order by id
```